# How Next.Js application does not reload even though they are Pre-rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, rest, next.js

I have been working with React and Next.Js in my career. Recently one of my juniors asked me if traditional websites used to reload because they used to fetch all the HTML, and CSS files from the server; Then how Next.js application **does not reload** even though they are also pre-rendered? As far as I know in Next.Js the HTML page is also generated on the server and the server sends the pre-rendered '**HTML FILE**' to the browser. It does not just fetch the JSON data. It fetches a full HTML page!!

I could not give any answer to him and I am also curious that how actually this thing happens? It would be great if you guys can help me to clarify my doubt.

Cheers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not reload"?

Comment: Do you mean the fact that Next.js doesn't fully reload the page on client-side page navigations?

Comment: I meant that the whole screen does not reload on each request. It basically gives the feel of a spa to users. But how? When HTML files are fetched. @juliomalves

Comment: Yes, you got me right. I am not 100% sure how the screen doesn't reload and gives the feel of a spa to users on client-side navigations. They basically work the same as traditional multipage websites. Don't they? But how Nex.js apps don't reload but traditional websites do? That's my confusion.

Comment: On client-side navigations Next.js does work like a SPA. It'll only fetch the full HTML from the server on initial page load, from then on it'll run JavaScript on the client, and fetch the data required for the page from the server as JSON (you can check the Network tab in devtools for these requests).

Comment: But don't the pages are prerendered on requests? When I see the network tab on google chrome developer tools, I see the whole HTML page is fetched from the server on each request. The built pages are generated in the next folder which is then served to the client. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Then why it's said that Nex.js pages are pre-rendered and served to the client? I am not 100% sure. Can you please help me to be more clear? @juliomalves

Comment: Pages do get pre-rendered on the server. It's just that pre-rendering is only relevant for the initial page load, where the server sends the HTML to the client - hydration still occurs on the client after receiving the HTML. When client-side navigations occur JavaScript runs on the client to generate the page, no HTML is sent from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts are in the right direction. It depends on the configuration. Nowadays we can be talking about Client Side rendering (CSR), Server Side Rendering (SSR) or Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR). With v13 of Next there's also a streaming feature.

But assuming that you are asking about Server Side Rendering, as a simplification, there are basically two types of navigation:

**Server Side Navigation**

- It happens when you enter one of the urls of your app, and also when you hit F5, cmd + R, and so on. This triggers the server side rendering. This means that your server will run your react app obtaining a partial HTML version (a.k.a. dehydrated) of your app, along with some script bundles.
- Then, your browser will run these bundles and perform the hydration, modifying the DOM according to your app logic.

**Client Side Navigation**

- Once the previous step was performed and you're already inside your app, it's usual to wrap your app's hyperlinks with next's `Link` component. By doing this, next will take control of what happens when you click them on client side.
- This will lead to an underlying XHR request to your server, which will contain a js bundle as response. This bundle builds the new page and replaces the corresponding parts of the DOM.

**Interesting facts**

- This Next's navigation handling is what allows the browser to mantain the state of, for example, the main layout without the need of rebuilding and rerendering it all the time.
- It also allows fancy things like prefetching. Most of your site is being built in background automatically which makes transitions between pages really fast.
- One of the greatest advantages of SSR (ISR...), in my opinion, is that search engines obtain a full static version of your app, having all the usefull semantic information, so, better SEO.
- ¿Have you ever encountered problems with window object in a SSR page? When your server is executting a part your app in server side, there's no window object, because server environment has no window abstraction (which seems logic, no screen, no window).

**Other rendering strategies**

CSR is basically what plain react does. (until v18, when Server Components were released). A bunch of JS bundles are served and run in browser.

ISR. In this case, your pages are generated in build time and served as static content. Your pages will be cached, but you can tune up the regeneration frequency in order to keep your pages updated and avoiding a full app rebuild / deploy.

[Server Side Rendering Simplified](https://medium.com/geekculture/server-side-rendering-simplified-fd708d5520ba#:%7E:text=Server%2Dside%20Rendering%20is%20simply,that%20the%20browser%20can%20process.)

[Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)

Hope it helps, suggestions / corrections are welcome!